# From flask import Flask fails with Syntax error: invalid syntax

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

The problem is that I am getting an error on some very basic code and I am not sure what is wrong

```
From flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Flask Dockerized'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0')
```

Here is what I am getting no matter how I run the project:

```
iulian@DESKTOP-CSHD28R MINGW64 /e/projects/Flask $ python app.py   File "app.py", line 1
    From flask import Flask
             ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"From" needs to be lowercased.